# Field Names for Struts2 map entries in a JSP

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2, collections, type-conversion

I want to populate a map property on a Struts2 action from a JSP. What is the format of the data names that I should use? Initially I am interested in populating a Map<String, String> but in the future I would be interesting in populating a Map<String, DomainClass> where the DomainClass has properties of its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an action, with a property as follows -

```
private Map<String,String> assetProps;
...
public Map<String, String> getAssetProps() {
    return assetProps;
}

public void setAssetProps(Map<String, String> assetProps) {
    this.assetProps = assetProps;
}
```

To set values onto the map, there are basically two steps. First off, OGNL can't instantiate the map, so it is up to you. In my action, I implement the Preparable interface, but instantiate it before running the 'public String input()' method as follows -

```
public class EditAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {
...
    public void prepare() {
        // just satisfying Preparable interface so we can have prepareInput()

    }

    public void prepareInput() throws Exception {
        assetProps = new HashMap<String,String>();
    }
```

Now, the object is non-null, I can use syntax similar to the following in the JSP -

```
  <s:iterator value="asset.properties" var="prop">
    <sjx:textfield name="%{'assetProps[\\'' +#prop.propName +'\\']'}" 
           value="%{#prop.propValue}" 
           label="%{#prop.propName}" size="25"/>
  </s:iterator>
```

The iterator pulls a set of objects off the stack and iterates over it. The important part is the "name=" section, notice the double-escaped single quotes. That way, when the page renders, the name of the input element becomes (for example) - assetProps['Screen Size']. When the page is submitted, inside the "public void execute()" method, assetProps is fully populated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this helped me resolve a similar situation. One side-note, you don't actually need the Preparable interface for this, you can just initialize the Map when its declared.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another code snippet doing something similar, in case it helps someone.

```
<s:iterator value="storageIds" var="sids">
    <s:hidden name="%{'storageIds[\\'' + key +'\\']'}" value="%{#sids.value}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

My action has a `Map<String,String>` named `storageIds`

When iterating a Map, key and value resolve to the `Map.Entry` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try This . Working perfectly for me

```
<s:iterator value="configMap" id="daa">
    <s:hidden name="%{'configMap[\\'' + key +'\\']'}" value="%{#daa.value}" />
</s:iterator>
```